# How can I add a column with numeric rank to the rows within a GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the table of employee data below:

```
Employee_id Employee_department Salary
100         ACCOUNTING          50000
200         SALES               75000
300         SALES               100000
400         ACCOUNTING          60000
```

Please help with a query to output the listing below, sequencing salary in descending order within each department where the highest salary is assigned sequence #1:

```
Employee_id Employee_department Salary Sequence
400         ACCOUNTING          60000  1
100         ACCOUNTING          50000  2
300         SALES               100000 1
200         SALES               75000  2
```

Thanks!

Comment: The term you're looking for is "RANK" and Googling on "oracle rank" turned up this article that seems to be exactly what you're looking for. http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rank.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use analytical functions for this, specifically the `RANK()` function:

```
SELECT
  Employee_id,
  Employee_department,
  Salary,
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_department ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS Sequence
FROM myTable
```

The PARTITION performs the ranking by department; remove it and you'll get a ranking across all departments.

The RANK will include ties, so if there are two people who share the highest salary in the department they'll both rank #1, and the next-highest salary will rank #3. If you want the next-highest salary to rank #2 instead of #3, use DENSE_RANK.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Employee_id, Employee_department, Salary,
RANK() WITHIN GROUP
   (ORDER BY Employee_department ASC, Salary DESC) "Sequence" 
FROM t
```

Ooops, WITHIN GROUP cant be used as an analytical,here is an alternative

```
SELECT Employee_id, Employee_department, Salary,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM t x 
         WHERE x.salary >= t.salary AND x.Employee_department =t.Employee_department ) AS  "Sequence"
FROM t
ORDER BY Employee_department ASC, Salary DESC
```